# Finding the maximum kinetic energy of any photoelectrons?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, photons, photoelectric-effect

An incident photon, $f=5.5\times 10^{14}\ Hz$, hits a metal with a work function of $2.8\ eV$.

How do I find the maximum kinetic energy of any photo-electrons?

I'm confused exactly how to do this, because I keep getting a negative kinetic energy. I have gotten 2.3 eV for the photon's energy, and I know the equation is $E_{\ in}$ - Work Function = $KE_{\ max}$, but 2.3-2.8 is a negative energy. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not doing this wrong. As you know energy of each photon is $E = hf = 2.27eV$  so they can't produce any photoelectrons on a metal with work function greater than that.